# post multiple form records in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am quite new to spring framework and I'm stuck with the following issues:
I am trying to insert multiple records on a single post request using Spring MVC 3.0
I successfully bound the List object and it is populating on JSP and when I submit the 
form the request is reaching on the  controller method(post) but the returned object does not contain proper values, its printing null.

My code is as follows:

```
form.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<f:form commandName="teamBean" method="post">
    <f:input path="players[0].fname" />
    <f:input path="players[0].lname" />
    <f:input path="players[0].phone" />
    <f:input path="players[0].email" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</f:form>

</body>
</html>

DynaminFormController.java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/form")
public class DynaminFormController {
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getForm(Map<String, TeamBean> map) {
    TeamBean teamBean = new TeamBean();

    players.add(new Player("dd", "dd", "dd", "dd"));
    players.add(new Player("cc", "cc", "cc", "cc"));
    teamBean.setPlayers(players);
    map.put("teamBean", teamBean);
            return "form";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postForm(TeamBean teamBean) {
    System.out.println("DynaminFormController.postForm()");
    System.out.println(teamBean);//printing null
    return "view";
}
}

TeamBean.java
public class TeamBean {
private List<Player> players;
    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(List<Player> players) {
    this.players = players;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TeamBean [players=" + players + "]";
}
}

Player.java
public class Player {

private String fname;
private String lname;
private String phone;
private String email;
public Player(String fname, String lname, String phone, String email) {

    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
}
///getters setters...
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Player [fname=" + fname + ", lname=" + lname + ", phone="
            + phone + ", email=" + email + "]";
}
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when you submit the form?

Comment: No there is no error while submitting form.

Comment: Please try adding a default constructor `public Player() {}` to Player class. Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `@ModelAttribute` on you Post Method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postForm(@ModelAttribute("teamBean") TeamBean teamBean) {
    System.out.println("DynaminFormController.postForm()");
    System.out.println(teamBean);//printing null
    return "view";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time jax but putting @ModelAttribute("teamBean") doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Add trace logging to your log4j and inspect any exceptions that are occurring after you submit the form.  `log4j.logger.org.springframework=TRACE`

Comment: Change `<f:form commandName="teamBean" method="post">` to `<f:form modelAttribute="teamBean" method="post">`

Comment: everything is fine in my log except this line  BeanUtils:410 - No property editor [java.lang.StringEditor] found for type java.lang.String according to 'Editor' suffix convention

Comment: It is a bit of a mystery, I would do some research on that error.  I found somewhere that someone had different version of spring.jar and spring-mvc.jar so you check that first.  Also try simplifying the problem.  Get something simple working (without any lists) then build up from that.

Comment: ok jax if u find any solution then please let me know,thanks again.

Comment: Hi everyone i have resolved my issue the problem was with spring's <f:input> tag ,i don't know why it was not working but just replace the <f:input> with html's <input> tag like:<input class="dy" name="players[0].fname"/>,though u may not get the populated values from controller but it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue, the problem was with spring's input tag ,i don't know why it was not working but just replace the f:input with html's input tag,though u may not get the populated values from controller but it's fine.

```
     <f:form commandName="teamBean" method="post">

        <tr>
            <td><input class="dy" name="players[0].fname" /></td>
            <td><input class="dy" name="players[0].lname" /></td>
            <td><input class="dy" name="players[0].phone" /></td>
            <td><input class="dy" name="players[0].email" /></td>
        </tr>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </f:form>
```